How do I reposition lag screws in garage after drywall is up?
My garage wall has 2x4 studs covered with 3/4" plywood (interior).  I have some wall-mounted storage shelves that are secured with 2" lag screws into the studs.   The city is requiring that I add type-X (5/8") drywall to all walls/ceiling.
What is the right way to pre-cut holes in the drywall for where the lag screws will be?  Or should I fill the hole with glue+sawdust and just reattach the shelves without first cutting the drywall?

Is the 3/4" plywood staying in place (i.e. drywall over it) or is it being replaced by drywall?

I think you're really asking how to transfer the locations of the screws (not bolts) through the drywall. Here's what I'd do.

Fit a drywall sheet so it's ready to install, and set it aside.

Install something pointy in your lag screw holes. This can be almost anything you have on hand, just so it's sharp enough to make a mark and protrudes slightly. 8d nails installed head-first might work well.

Position the sheet, then press firmly at each screw location to make a mark.

Remove the sheet, then run a small drill bit through at each punch mark.


This may not get you ultra-precise, but when it comes time to reinstall the shelves the lag screws should find the original holes without much trouble. Of course, you could accomplish the same thing by measuring horizontally and vertically from reference lines such as the edge of the last sheet and the ceiling.
Regarding screw length, 2" was fine before, but you'll now have 5/8" less penetration. Since you have the 3/4" plywood (which is good backing in its own right), I would go to a 2-1/2" screw. Assuming the holes weren't initially overbored it'll hold just fine at ~1½" penetration. If you're fairly confident you won't find plumbing in the wall, you could go to 3". Pilot about half the screw's shank diameter or you risk twisting a longer screw's head off.

Yep, and worst case, if you can't find something suitably pointy to put in the hole (I mean, even toothpicks could work), you can use paint on the stud.  The hole in the paint is where your hole in the drywall should be drilled before you screw it to the studs.

Assuming they want the drywall in there for fire safety, they are not going to be happy seeing it installed with lots of holes.
But that really isn't a big deal. Cutting the holes later is trivial, and actually cutting them before you put up the drywall would be relatively hard to get the holes lined up. The main thing will just be to carefully measure where the holes in the plywood and studs are so that you can hit the right spots later. You don't need a big drill to get through drywall - in fact you don't need a drill at all, just a drywall saw or even a screwdriver or a knife.
A bigger concern I have is whether the lag bolts will hold securely when reinstalled. They won't go quite as deep as before, because of the new layer of drywall, and they won't really bite into the studs as much because they are going in old holes. There are two solutions:

If the bolts - and the existing holes - are small enough, use a new set of slightly larger bolts in the same holes.
If you really want to reuse the bolts, install the shelves a little higher or lower than before and drill new holes for the existing bolts.

If the drywall is over the plywood and not replacing the plywood then 2" bolts seem rather short. 2" - 1/4" (shelf support) - 3/4" = 1" into the studs, which actually isn't all that much. If you subtract another 5/8" then you are at 3/8" (1/2" if your shelf supports aren't so thick) and that really isn't enough. New 3" lag bolts would be a much better choice.
As far as filling the holes first: That makes sense in certain limited situations - e.g., fill a hole in wood that is going to be painted, or fill a hole for a hinge screw before putting in a new larger screw. But here the holes will be covered by drywall, so there is no reason to bother filling them whether they are going to be reused (won't provide enough extra strength to help much for shelves) or not (covered, so who cares). Filling the holes also won't make any substantive difference in the strength of the studs.

I agree with this answer, but recommend using longer bolts.  the drywall has reduced the useful length by 5/8".

@RMDman As I said: They won't go quite as deep as before

I understand however with 2" bolts and assuming just a 1/8 " shelf bracket and 5/8" drywall, that leaves only 1 1/4"  to bind into a stud.  Not much considering it is expected to hold up a shelf with unknown weight.

@RMDman 1-1/4" would be OK. It is much worse because I assume that the 3/4" plywood is staying in place. If so, it is actually 1/2"...

In the interest of safety I would use 3 inch bolts if it were my shelves in my garage.  The cost of new bolts is far less that the cost of damage to a car when a shelf falls or an injured person.  Better safe than sorry.
